# Django user authentication not working on every subpage

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates

i have strange (and probable simple) problem with user authentication in Django.
I added to base.html file this code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>{{user.get_username}} is logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in!</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a></a>
{% endif %}
```

Then i added this line to every other template:

> ﻿{% extends "base.html" %}

It looks good because every subpage display this lines of code, unfortunately sometimes is displaying code when user is authenticated and sometimes where he is not authenticated.For example when i switch between two subpages once i get information that user with his login is logged, on this second webpage i get information that i am not logged in and when i come back to that first subpage i am again authenticated...

How could i change it? What could be a problem?

my views about login:

```
def login_user(request):
    login_user = {}
    login_user.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', login)


def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('invalidlogin')


def logged_in(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                              {'user': request.user})
```

and my 'login' urls:

```
path('login', views.login, name='login'),
path('authorized', views.auth_view, name='authorized'),
path('loggedout', views.loggedout, name='loggedout'),
path('loggedin', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
path('invalidlogin', views.invalidlogin, name='invalidlogin'),
```

Comment: You  better try to use decorator like @require_user, and apply  it to the view.

Comment: thank you for your response @ilyas-jumadurdyew, but how can i use this decorator to work on every subpage?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: Thnk you, I read about it in the link. As i understand this decorator works with view which i want to use on my subpage. But what if i want this authentication it on every subpage? For example on homepage when i don't have any views, just some basics i want to display user's name.